# Is it possible to open an AX ssrs report in the same window?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, axapta, ssrs-2012, microsoft-dynamics

I want to click on a Textbox in the report and behind the textbox there is a action which says go to the same report again with some value in a parameter. This works fine, but every time i click on the textbox, the report will be load in a new window. My goal is to load the report in the same window again.

Is think this is possible, but i don't know how.

Here is a Screenshot from the actual Textbox properties.

[image: Here]

Expr = `=IIF(InStr(Parameters!ApprovalProcessDS_creditors.Value, Fields!VENDACCOUNT.Value) > 0, Parameters!ApprovalProcessDS_creditors.Value, Parameters!ApprovalProcessDS_creditors.Value & Fields!VENDACCOUNT.Value & ";")`

Omit = false

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: No, it cannot be done.

I claim no proof, refute if you can.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jan. Is it possible when the report is opened via browser?